# stale NFS file handle

Tags: azure, nfs, azure-files

Our Azure file share mounted on pods using like [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux%20approach)

We are a seeing stale NFS file-handle on one specific file can we every time we ask our program to create and write that file we are seeing the program terminate reporting us  `stale NFS file handle`

But creating the file using the UNIX utility
`echo "hello" > the-file.txt` on the mounted file share seems to work.

What is the problem here? **All the other files are getting created except this one file.**

The relevant code is in `golang` and it look like this.

```
    ...
    s.csvFile, err = snowflakeFile(filePath, data)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer s.cleanup()
    ...
```

```
func snowflakeFile(path string, data EventData) (*os.File, error) {
    filename := fmt.Sprintf("%s-%s-%s.csv", data.Type, md5Sum(data.RemoteServer), filepath.Base(path))
    filename = filepath.Join(config.Fetch("CSV_DIR"), filename)
    return os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_TRUNC, 0644)
}
```

```
func (b *base) cleanup() error {
    err := b.csvFile.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("[%s] Error closing the file handler %s: %+v", b.Type, b.csvFile.Name(), err)
    }
    return err
}
```

Comment: Hi, its broad as a question IMO as we don't know how you open the file, do you release the file after the opening ?.. To see the code might help too, but it's broad IMO

Comment: added relevant code.